# Reshape 1D List to 2D List -Python

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
a = ['2', '3', '4', '7', '5']
```

I want to transform to a 2D matrix knowing that I have 4 columns, I do not consider rows here

I want to achieve this without repeating the items, just fill the rest with `None` or empty space as follows:

```
New_a = [['2', '3', '4', '7'],
         ['5', None, None, None]]
```

I tried to reshape it using reshape function, but it did not work, because the target matrix is not consistent.

I also tried (resize function). It did not work because it repeat the items once there are some gaps at the end.

Comment: You said you are trying to use `reshape` but nowhere do you suggest you are using Numpy. If you are, you will get better answers if you let people know you are using it (and show your code).

Comment: Python does not have matrices. It has Lists of Lists but this is not the same thing as a 2-D array and hence there is no concept of `reshape` nor of `columns`. Numpy does provide for 2-D arrays and these can be resized - for example by converting your List to a Numpy array and using `a.resize((2,4))` which will extend your List with empty strings (because you originally used string elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New_a = []
a = ['2', '3', '4', '7', '5']
for i in range(0,len(a),4) :
    New_a.append(a[i:i+4])
if len(New_a[-1]) != 4 :
    New_a[-1] += [None]*(4-len(New_a[-1])) 
print(New_a)
```

output :-

```
[['2', '3', '4', '7'], ['5', None, None, None]]
```

This should work for different lengths of the 1d array `a`

You can also use reisze() function of numpy array but it will fill your array with empty strings instead of None.

Example :-

```
a = ['2', '3', '4', '7', '5']
a1=np.array(a)
a1.resize((int(np.ceil(len(a)/4)),4))
```

`a1` will look like this:-

```
array([['2', '3', '4', '7'],
       ['5', '', '', '']], dtype='<U1')
```